# Java - Odd behaviour of List contains

Tags: java

Just I came across a snippet of code,

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("A");
a.add("B");
a.add("C");

List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
b.add("A");
b.add("B");
b.add("C");

System.out.println("a.contains(b)"+a.contains(b));
```

is returning false what I expected is `true` value.

I stunned, to see this behavior of the `contains` method provided by `java`. Is this expected behavior, and what is use of this `contains` method in `List`

Comment: If List a contains "A", "B" and "C": How can it contain b, another List?

Comment: `contains` is elementhood (∈), not subset (⊆) or subsequence.

Comment: This behavior is expected, and it works as intended!

Comment: What about reading Javadoc before asking a question?

Comment: [A B C of Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a.contains(b)` checks is a single element `b` is contained in the List `a`, which is clearly false in your example, since none of the elements of `a` is a `List`.

You are looking for `a.containsAll(b)`, which checks if all the elements in the `Collection` `b` exist in `a`.

Read the Javadoc :

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list contains the specified element.
 * More formally, returns <tt>true</tt> if and only if this list contains
 * at least one element <tt>e</tt> such that
 * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(e))</tt>.
 * ...
 */
boolean contains(Object o);

/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list contains all of the elements of the
 * specified collection.
 * ...
 */
boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c);
```

Comment: It's also possible the questioner is looking for a subsequence test (like `String.contains`), in which case I don't think `List` comes with a method for that.

Comment: @Eran, I got it , whereas `a.contains("A")` or `a.contains("B")` will return `true`

Answer (score 1):

`contains` checks for the existence of a single element in the list.  You want to use `containsAll` when checking to see if a list contains all of the elements of another list.

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("A"); 
a.add("B");
a.add("C"); 

List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(); 
b.add("A"); 
b.add("B");
b.add("C");

//Both of these will print true
System.out.println("a.contains(\"B\"): " + a.contains("B"));
System.out.println("a.containsAll(b): " + a.containsAll(b));
```